# Datagrids and Classic ASP

Tags: datagrid, asp-classic

to maintain compatibility with a classic ASP system, I essentially need to build the equivalent of an ASP.NET datagrid (complete with read, insert and update capability) in Classic ASP, are there any tools out there that make this any easier than just simply handcoding tables?  I'm fairly rusty at Classic ASP as well so an easy solution is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to check out [ajaxed Datatable](http://www.ajaxed.org/articles/Datatable/)

Start with [Understanding Datatables](http://www.ajaxed.org/article/Using--Understanding-Datatables/22/)

Comment: FYI, these links may have worked at one point but they don't anymore.

Answer (score 2):

There are no pure "ASP" solutions to this.  However there are plenty of commercial Javascript based AJAX backed data grids that can work from an ASP server.

What really are your "compatibility" requirements?  Why not do this with ASP.NET?

Of course you might consider using a Silverlight Datagrid, you could make that work with an ASP backend as well.

Comment: Need to work with classic ASP as I'm at an organization that has no .NET Experience and is not immediately inclined to make all their developers learn .NET.  Silverlight is likely out of the question too...I suppose I can rig up some Javascript to communicate on the back to ASP but that's making a lot of work...

Comment: @tekiegreg:  You want acheive something complex with what is ultimately a simple tool.  You have no choice but to do "a lot of work" or buy in a commercial Javascript data grid.